# How to add edge length as a weight in betweeness centrality using OSMNx/Networkx?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, networkx

I'm using Python library OSMNx to get the betweenness centrality of a given street network G. Form what I see, the module  [osmnx.stats.extended_stats(G, bc=True)](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html)  computes betweenness using NetworkX module [networkx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=True, weight=None)](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html) setting  all edge weights as equal. Since the edge length is already embedded in G, it would be straightforward to use it as a weight. Still I'm not able to find a way to do it.

How can I set the weight to be 1/length using these two libraries?

Please consider the graph given by the following example

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

#Using OSMNx
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(37.79, 37.78, -122.41, -122.43, network_type='drive')
stats = ox.extended_stats(G,bc=True)
bet1 = stats["betweenness_centrality"]

#Using NetworkX
bet2 = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight=None)
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd

l = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'length')
l = pd.Series(l).to_frame()
w=1/l
w = w.to_dict(orient="index")
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, w, 'w')
bet3 = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight='w')
```

But I'm arriving to exactly the same result as using no weights.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the edge data? For example with g.edges(data=True)?

Comment: Yes I have. The data related to each edge is there and it can be used as a weight. However, from what I see, setting `weight=None`, `weight='length'` or `weight='w'` (with w=1/length) returns the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have detected a bug in `networkx` handling of `MultiDiGraph` in the shortest path algorithms. See following example:

```py
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,1), (2,3,2), (1,3,1)])
print(nx.betweenness_centrality(graph))
# {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}
print(nx.betweenness_centrality(graph, weight="weight"))
# {1: 0.5, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}


multi_di_graph = nx.MultiDiGraph()
multi_di_graph.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,1), (2,3,2), (1,3,1)])
print(nx.betweenness_centrality(multi_di_graph))
# {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}
print(nx.betweenness_centrality(multi_di_graph, weight="weight"))
# {1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0}
```

The error is in the 
`_single_source_dijkstra_path_basic`
especially the following [code lines](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/centrality/betweenness.html)

```py
for w, edgedata in G[v].items():
    vw_dist = dist + edgedata.get(weight, 1)
```

I'm not sure if the shortest path algorithms in `networkx` should work for multigraph, but since I've found no note, I think it's a bug. 
I would suggest, you open an issue on the [networkx GitHub](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues).
If it is possible for the regarding part, you could think about casting to a usual `DiGraph`, too.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer and clear example. I partially solved my issue as you suggested, by converting the `MultiDiGraph` into `Graph` or `Digraph` (I'm still looking at the differences in results by these two). I also opened a new issue in [NetworkX GitHub](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3432).

Comment: Seems like they want to solve this issue for the 2.4 version. Before that you can create a DiGraph with the minimal edge weight of all edges between two nodes. The difference between DiGraph and Graph will be on all pairs of nodes, where only one edge is present or weights are different. Upvoting and/or accepting answer would be great ;)

Answer (score 0):

> the module osmnx.stats.extended_stats(G, bc=True) computes betweenness using NetworkX module networkx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=True, weight=None) setting all edge weights as equal. Since the edge length is already embedded in G, it would be straightforward to use it as a weight.

OSMnx [automatically uses edge lengths](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/d5ae24aa3f125ee8d7980438525e03d2679fa280/osmnx/stats.py#L422) as the weight when calculating betweenness centrality. For any further customization, you can just call `nx.betweenness_centrality(G)` directly on your OSMnx graph object, and parameterize it as desired.

Comment: Dear Geoff thanks for your prompt reply and congratulations for your amazing package! I'm still a bit confused of how betweenness is computed. Following my earlier example, once G is retrieved form OSMnx `ox.extended_stats(G,bc=True)`, `nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight=None)` and `nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight='length')` provide exactly the same result. That's why I was assuming that OSMnx do not uses edge lengths as weights.

Comment: @gboeing: From my test above and since you are using instances of `MultiDiGraph`, the call in OSMNx is correct, but `networkx` will return the results without any weights. See the example in my answer.

Comment: Yes, looks like an upstream bug report should be opened on networkx's github issues.